# How to populate a ListView from a SqLite DataBase?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I will build an app where the user can manage a littel Database. Ad exemple add films that i have seen. So the first textView is for the name of the film, the second textView for the producer and the third textView for the Director.

In java i can make the layout for the listView and can make the SqLite DataBase. But my problem is that i can't connect the database with the listView. I have serched any tutorials but i don't find it. Can anyone indicate a good tutorial that It is right for me please? Thanks.

Comment: Check for cursoradapter

Comment: Check this: http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-listview

Comment: Here's the official documentation for cursor adapter: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html